# How to check the version of urllib

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I created a python virtual env. As `urllib` is a standard library, I am able to import it directly using `import urllib`. I want to find out what version of urllib is installed. I tried checking in `site-packages` but could not find the library there. I tried doing `urllib.__version` after `import urllib`. But it's throwing the error `AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute '__version__'`. How can I find the `urllib` version?

Comment: Standard modules doesn't have version. You can check the Python version to understand if a feature is included or not.

Answer (score 1):

In python2.7, you can simply get:

```
Python 2.7.18 (v2.7.18:8d21aa21f2, Apr 20 2020, 13:25:05)
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.__version__
'1.17'
>>>
```

In Python3, `urllib` was separated to multiple packages, so you need to get the version from `urllib.request`:

```
Python 3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.__version__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute '__version__'
>>> import urllib.request
>>> urllib.request.__version__
'3.9'
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you try to install it , it will show the output as - which shows it is already installed

```
root@lancer:# pip install urllib3
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (1.26.2)
```